# runtime error: addition of unsigned offset overflowed

Tags: graph, backtracking, flood-fill

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool isSafe(vector<vector<int>> &image, int sr, int sc, int initial_value){
        if(sr>=0 && sr<image.size() && sc>=0 && sc<image[0].size() && image[sr][sc]==initial_value)
        {
            return true;
            
        }
    return false;
        
    
}
vector<vector<int>> floodFill(vector<vector<int>>& image, int sr, int sc, int newColor) {
    int initial_value=image[sr][sc];
    image[sr][sc]=newColor;
    
    if(isSafe(image, sr+1, sc,  initial_value))
    {
        // image[sr+1][sc]=newColor;
        image=floodFill( image,  sr+1,  sc,  newColor);
    }
    if(isSafe(image, sr-1, sc,  initial_value))
    {
        // image[sr+1][sc]=newColor;
        image=floodFill( image,  sr-1,  sc,  newColor);
    }
    if(isSafe(image, sr, sc+1,  initial_value))
    {
        // image[sr+1][sc]=newColor;
        image=floodFill( image,  sr,  sc+1,  newColor);
    }
    if(isSafe(image, sr, sc-1,  initial_value))
    {
        // image[sr+1][sc]=newColor;
        image=floodFill( image,  sr-1,  sc,  newColor);
    }
    return image;
}
```

};

Comment: Use debugger to find wjhat line the error occurs at

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
vector<vector<int>> floodFill(vector<vector<int>>& image, ...
```

Since you are passing the image by reference, there is no need to return it by value.

You will improve performance greatly by using

```
void floodFill(vector<vector<int>>& image, int sr, int sc, int newColor) {
    int initial_value=image[sr][sc];
    image[sr][sc]=newColor;
    
    if(isSafe(image, sr+1, sc,  initial_value))
    {
        floodFill( image,  sr+1,  sc,  newColor);
    }
    if(isSafe(image, sr-1, sc,  initial_value))
    {
        floodFill( image,  sr-1,  sc,  newColor);
    }
    if(isSafe(image, sr, sc+1,  initial_value))
    {
        floodFill( image,  sr,  sc+1,  newColor);
    }
    if(isSafe(image, sr, sc-1,  initial_value))
    {
        floodFill( image,  sr-1,  sc,  newColor);
    }
}
```